# "NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed when calling post method from angular.js with web api

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api

I want to save som fields from angular
I have following code :

```
<script>
    angular.module('ProductAdd', [])
    .controller('ProductAddController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.submit = function () {
            if ($scope.Nume) {
                var product = {
                    "Nume": $scope.Nume,
                    "Prenume": $scope.Prenume,
                    "CNP": $scope.CNP,
                    "Telefon": $scope.Telefon
                }
                console.log(product);
                $http.post('http://localhost:1110/api/product', product).
                success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    alert('Product Added Successfully');
                }).
                error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log(config, status);
                    alert("error");
                });
            }
        };
    }]);

</script>
```

In web APi i have following controller 
:

```
public class ProductController : ApiController
{

    public static Lazy<List<Pacient>> products = new Lazy<List<Pacient>>();//Static variable use only for demo, don’t use unless until require in project. 
    public static int PgaeLoadFlag = 1; // Page load count. 
    public static int ProductID = 4;

    // GET api/product
    public List<Pacient> GetAllProducts() //get method
    {
        //Instedd of static variable you can use database resource to get the data and return to API
        return products.Value; //return all the product list data
    }

    // GET api/product/5
    public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id)
    {
        Pacient product = products.Value.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.PacientID == id);
        if (product == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(product);
    }

   // POST api/product
    public void ProductAdd(Pacient product) //post method
    {
        product.PacientID = ProductID;
        products.Value.Add(product); //add the post product data to the product list
        ProductID++;
        //instead of adding product data to the static product list you can save data to the database.
    }
```

But when i want to save a product i get

"NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed - http://localhost:1110/api/product"

And 2 warnings:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:1110/api/product. (Reason: CORS preflight channel did not succeed).
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:1110/api/product. (Reason: CORS request failed).

Answer (score 0):

Could you check if your pre flight. Check is fine or failing I.e a request with verb 'options' failed with an error 403. I got a similar issue when trying to post data from angular app to web api